# norm of $n$-th covariant derivative of smooth function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The question is how define the norm of $n$-th covariant derivative of smooth function $f$ on a manifold $M$. The manifold is two dimensional so maybe I can do it in the following way: thing about $n$-th covariant derivative as $2^n$ dimensional vector and take it $L^p$ norm?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is any section of a vector bundle $E$ over a smooth manifold $M$ and if $\nabla$ is any covariant derivative on $E$, then $\nabla A$ is a section of $T^*M \otimes E$, and this has a natural (pointwise) inner product $g \otimes h$ given a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ and a fibre metric $h$ on $E$, defined by $\langle \alpha \otimes s , \beta \otimes t \rangle_{g \otimes h} = g(\alpha, \beta) h(s, t)$. Now, if you want some kind of *global* norm, one can take this pointwise norm and do a number of things: if $M$ is compact and oriented (and sometimes even if not), one can take $L^p$ norms by $|| \nabla A ||^p_{L^P} = \int_M | \nabla A |^p_{g \otimes h} \mathrm{vol_g}$, where $\mathrm{vol_g}$ is the volume form associated to the metric $g$ and chosen orientation. One can also consider $C^k$ norms, Holder norms, and various others.

For your specific question, $\nabla^n f$ is a section of $\otimes^n T^* M$, and thus one only needs a metric $g$ on $M$ to define the pointwise norm.

Comment: I should add that your question really has nothing to do with the dimension of the manifold.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of analysis it is usually more convenient to define your favorite class of function spaces via local coordinates and a partition of unity. More precisely consider your favorite (compact manifold) and choose a covering $U_i$ together with charts $\phi_i:B_1\rightarrow U_i,$ where $B_1$ denotes the unit ball in your model space and such that $\phi$ extends to the closures, and a partition of unity $(\chi_i)$ subordinate to your covering. The you define

$\|f\|_{W^{k,p}(M)}:=\sum_i \|\phi_i^\ast (\chi_if)\|_{W^{k,p}(B_1)}$ for $f\in C^\infty(M).$

This norm is independent of the choices as long as $M$ is compact and its closure is a Banach space. Vector bundles can be treated similarly. Of course this defines a norm which equivalent to choosing a metric and a connection $\nabla$ and to consider

$\|f\|:=\|\nabla^k f\|_{L^p}+\|f\|_{L^p},$

as in Spiro's answer.

Comment: This sort of norm is inconvenient if we want to apply, for example, Bochner's method, or Griffiths positivity, or more generally if we want to use information about the curvature of a metric to imply results about the solutions in various Sobolev or Hoelder spaces of various linear systems of partial differential equations on sections of vector bundles. Spiro's answer has an advantage, despite its conceptual complexity.